# what are the options of showinfo in tkMessagebox module?

Tags: python, tkmessagebox

help on showinfo() is quite laconic:

```
Help on function showinfo in module tkMessageBox:
showinfo(title=None, message=None, **options)
  Show an info message
```

Where can I find more information about possible options?

Comment: Googling some documentation or tutorials is probably a good start...

Comment: Maybe this http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Of course I googled first. But found nothing 'official'

Comment: @zetysz: Thanks.It contains the required information. But is there any 'official' documentation for this module ?

Comment: @zety The link is broken.

Comment: @SuitBoyApps You can find it at  https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkMessageBox.html